# self join tables vs cte recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

I have a curiosity. please suggest me the best practices here.

I have a table test that contains empname and mgr_name columns as the name suggest empname contains empname and mgr_name contains manager name for the particular employee. my requirement is to find those employees who at least report to one manager + employees who are managers.

I write a query and that is returning correct records.

```
create table test(empname varchar(10),mgr_name varchar(10))

insert into test
values('a','b'),('b',null),('c',null),('d','f'),('f',null),('g',null),('h',null)
```

query :

```
select a.empname
from test a , test b
where a.mgr_name =b.empname
union
select b.empname
from test a , test b
where a.mgr_name =b.empname
```

i tried to optimize this query and use CTE instead of using tables in self join multiple times like

```
;with cte as (
select *
from test

)
select a.empname
from cte a , cte b
where a.mgr_name =b.empname
union
select b.empname
from cte a , cte b
where a.mgr_name =b.empname
```

But I found that there is no improvement showing in the execution plan.

I need your help to decide to optimize query in this case, please suggest if any other approach would be optimize in this case.

Comment: **[Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)**

Comment: Without sharing the plans, STATS IO and DDL of those approaches how can we help?

Comment: *why* did you think that introducing a CTE would help here?

Comment: Do you really need to remove duplicate rows? If not, do `UNION ALL`?

Comment: That is not recursion and CTE is just syntax

Comment: I'm not actually sure what the volume of downvotes is for. The OP has actually provided consumable sample data, which is a very nice change compared the volume that are posted without. They've also shown what they have tried. The downvotes seem to be more because of the OP's lack of knowledge of SQL (such as their use of implicit JOIN's and thoughts that a CTE would help).

Comment: @Lamu, I believe many people are turned off by the terrible join syntax.

Comment: It's curious that you've never received an acceptable answer to one of your questions at SO. Perhaps there is another community that could be of help. Or perhaps you don't realize that asking people to take time to help you warrants at least some feedback on your part. 'Tis the season.

Answer (score 0):

Optimization to the specified metrics (none) results in the following to provide a list of all people and whether they are (1) managed by someone or (b) managing someone:

```
declare @Employees as Table ( EmployeeName VarChar(10), ManagerName  VarChar(10) );

insert into @Employees ( EmployeeName, ManagerName ) values
  ( 'a', 'b' ), ( 'b', null ), ( 'c', null ), ( 'd', 'f' ), ( 'f', null ), ( 'g', null ), ( 'h', null );

select distinct( Name ),
  case when exists
    ( select 42 from @Employees where EmployeeName = Name and ManagerName is not NULL ) then 1 else 0 end as IsManaged,
  case when exists
    ( select 42 from @Employees where ManagerName = Name ) then 1 else 0 end as IsManager
  from (
    select EmployeeName as Name
      from @Employees
    union all
    select ManagerName
      from @Employees
      where ManagerName is not NULL ) as PH;

-- Alternatively:
select Name, Max( IsManaged ) as IsManaged, Max( IsManager ) as IsManager
  from (
    select EmployeeName as Name, case when ManagerName is NULL then 0 else 1 end as IsManaged, 0 as IsManager
      from @Employees
    union all
    select ManagerName, 0, 1
      from @Employees
      where ManagerName is not NULL ) as PH
  group by Name;
```

Self-management is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your CTE does not do anything. You are just copying one table exactly, so there is not difference from using cte or test. You probably meant to do something like:

```
; with cte as (
    select * -- This won't work because duplicate naming, but you can change that
    from test a, test b -- my soul weeps at this terrible syntax
)
```

In any case, you don't need to do this. Here's the query that you want

```
select empname
from test
where mgr_name is not null
    or empname in (
        select mgr_name
            from test
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to query the table 4 times... Just check to see if `mgr_name` has a value of *`NULL`*:

```
SELECT empname
FROM test
WHERE mgr_name IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT mgr_name
FROM test
WHERE mgr_name IS NOT NULL;
```

You'll still need to do 2 scans, but get's rid of the implicit `JOIN` as well as 2 scans (as in your query the table was scanned twice on each side of the `UNION`).

Comment: Not the same as this misses FK not present

Comment: @Paparazzi "not the same" as what? What foreign key? The OP does not specify any keys on the DDL. The query above gives the same result set as the OP's. Please elaborate when you comment: "does not work" is never helpful.

Comment: Exactly, OP does not specify key.  This will delete even if mgr_name is not valid.

Comment: @Paparazzi `DELETE`? I've provided a `SELECT` statement. It won't delete anything.

Comment: i am only asking for better query in this case. i understand that this depend on amount of data but please consider the rowcount would be around 3000 in this case with index on empname column

Comment: @nextaxtion you're not going to get away with less than 2 scans on the table with your set up.